# Yum install graphicsmagick on rhel server

Tags: yum

Any idea how do i install `graphicsmagick` using `yum` on `rhel 6`?
I know the other method of installing i.e by downloading tar file and running make install and so on. However i was wondering if we can install it through package manager like yum, so that it will be easier to un-install if required in future.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the epel repository in order to do this.

Download the latest epel-release rpm from

```
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/
```

Install epel-release rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
```

Install GraphicsMagick rpm package:

```
yum install GraphicsMagick
```

Comment: The above command worked for me. Thank you, i have accepted your answer. However i was wondering can we specify any specific version?